# Unable to merge XML Document Content from Word 2010 files

Tags: c#, openxml, office-2007, openxml-sdk, office-2010

I am using the `altChunkId` element to merge DOCX document files, but am unable to see the content of the control XML element.

I think this is because the reference for which XML to take the content of is from the folder it was merged to instead of the folder itself.

In Word 2007 the file shows the content of the content control while in Word 2010 it's blank.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open word 2010.
2. Go to developer tab.
3. Add "Plain Text Content Control".
4. Save As `a.docx`
5. Create the XML binding with [Word 2007 content control toolkit](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/acoat/archive/2007/03/01/linking-word-2007-content-controls-to-custom-xml.aspx)
6. Copy `a.docx` to a new file `b.docx`.
7. Code to merge:

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.IO;
   using System.IO.Packaging;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Xml;
   using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
   using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
   using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
   using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;

   class Class1
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           string doc2 = @"b.docx";
           string doc1 = @"a.docx";
           using (var myDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(doc2, true))
           {
               string altChunkId = "AltChunkId1";
               var mainPart2 = myDoc.MainDocumentPart;

               var chunk = mainPart2.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(
               AlternativeFormatImportPartType.WordprocessingML, altChunkId);
               using (var fileStream = File.Open(doc1, FileMode.Open))
               {
                   chunk.FeedData(fileStream);
                   AltChunk altChunk = new AltChunk();
                   altChunk.Id = altChunkId;
                   mainPart2.Document.Body.InsertAfter(altChunk, mainPart2.Document.Body.Elements<Paragraph>().Last());
                   mainPart2.Document.Save();
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
8. Open `b.docx` with Word 2010 and you will see that the plain text content control is empty.
9. Open `b.docx` with Word 2007 and you will see that the plain text content control is NOT empty.

Comment: Can you post b.docx somewhere where we can take a look?

Comment: Can you share the code and documents. MS has removed Custom XML support however since you are using data bound Content Controls that shouldn't be the issue.